# Modal não carrega os dados que estão vindo do banco corretamente

Tags: php, javascript, html, aplicação-web, dom

Bom dia.

Pessoal tô com um probleminha que é o seguinte.

Estou mostrando na view um tabela, onde caso uma coluna tenha um determinado status será mostrar um link para abrir um model onde será mostrado os dados que estão no banco.

dei um var_dump no array e os dados estão vindo corretos, porém ele não pega os dados da row relacionado na posição do foreach, ele sempre repete como se fosse a primeira linha.

VIEW>

```
<?php if($role['dr_status'] == "3") { ?>
                            <!-- <?php $desligamento = $this->Clinic_model->get_cancel_description($role['dr_id']); ?>
                            <?php var_dump($desligamento) ?> -->
                            <span style="color: red; font-weight:600"><?php echo "Desligamento solicitado" ?>
                              <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                <span style="margin-left: 10px; cursor: pointer"> ver motivo </span>
                              </a>
                            </span>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #00C0EF; color: white; font-weight: 600">
                                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="font-weight: 600">Desligamento solicitado</h5>
                                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                      </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body" style="font-weight: 600">
                                      <p> <?php echo $role['cancel']; ?> </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer col-12">
                                      <p> Deseja realmente desligar esse médico </p><br>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">SIM</button>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Voltar</button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          <?php } ?>
```

[image: essa é a tabela que estou criando, quando clica em ver detalhes abre o modal]

essa é a tabela que estou criando, quando clica em ver detalhes abre o modal >
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está o problema todos os modais mostram sempre o mesmo dados, Acho que tem relação com o DOM, mas não consegui resolver o problema. De preferencia se for feito em php mesmo.

obrigado.

Comment: Você está usando ajax para fazer as requisições dos dados?

Comment: não, estou usando o próprio php com framework codeigniter.

Comment: Sugiro que cada link tenha um id, e que quando clique no link abra um modal execute um ajax que faz a consulta no banco e imprima no corpo do modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa fazer é, criar um modal para cada item. E o que você, muito provavelmente está fazendo é criando um único modal e dizendo que todos os itens apontam para aquele modal. O que você poderia fazer é, na `div` do modal, colocar algum identificador, como o próprio ID do item no seu DB.

```
para cada $registro:
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal-<?php echo $registro->id; ?>">
        ...
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-<?php echo $registro->id; ?>">
        ...
```

Comment: A ideia é boa, mas será que não vai atrasar o carregamento da página? caso ele tenha 100 registros, serem criados 100 modais? não seria mais interessante um unico modal que retornaria os dados do registro escolhido?

Comment: então... bom, ele poderia criar um único modal, e quando for clicado sobre o botão de exibição, ele consultar via ajax o banco, e alimentar o modal com os dados retornados, como você disse.

Comment: criei os ids conforme os registros no banco, porém como faço pra acessar isso quando o usuario der um click? pode ser usando o jquery > $("#btn_modal").click(function(){... }